# ModuleInit Fody Initialize not called

Tags: c#, wpf, fody

I've a WPF application that loads 3 different assembly which containts application extensions. I've added to the 3 projects the ModuleInit.Fody and for now just put a Console.WriteLine("module")

I load the assemblies with this piece of code

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyApplication.Modules*.dll");

        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            AssemblyName assamblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file);

            var assembly = Assembly.Load(assamblyName); //this throw an exception
         //   AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName()
            //var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

            assembly.GetTypes().First();
            assemblies.Add(assembly);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

## UPDATE1 you can find a demo [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6nPFuIuKHG1M3FBT1c0RXNaams/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What exception? What does it says?

Comment: Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\\projects\\demo\\WPFComposition\\ModuleB\\bin\\Debug\\ModuleB.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Comment: If you can just download the project...it's 500kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module initializer is run the first time any type from that assembly is used. NOT when the module is loaded